# Prevent Firefox "Search for" Context Item from Taking Focus

Tags: windows-7, firefox

The 'search' context item in Firefox currently moves focus to the new tab with search results. This wasn't always the case; is there any way to revert to the old behavior?

I'm currently using Nightly build *Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20130508 Firefox/23.0 ID:20130508031113 CSet: b980d32c366f*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, focussing the tab is still the default behaviour on Aurora for Mac. Anyway, you can change it:

1. Enter `about:config` in your URL bar
2. Click OK on the warning (if presented)
3. Search for `browser.search.context.loadInBackground`
4. Double-click to toggle between `true` and `false` (`true` is the behaviour that you want)